# Critical error on Linux installed in AMD computer after deleting /boot/intel-ucode.img

Tags: arch-linux, boot, intel, amd

It is puzzling to me that deleting `/boot/intel-ucode.img` could cause a critical error on a Linux installation in an AMD computer. Could you please clarify how this works?

The operating system is Arch Linux, and I would like to remove the file while still keeping the OS running.

Comment: To get proper help, please state your distribution ([edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/745296/edit) the question). For example your example doesn't happen on Debian 11 where the microcode is embedded as an additional cpio in the single initramfs image file. I guess you're using Arch Linux, but that's just a guess. Of course deleting a file which is expected to be present by the OS, even if it won't be needed in the end, leads to problems.

Comment: I rephrased the text. Please correct it further if I misunderstood your intention with the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your bootloader can load your initramfs from multiple component files.

If `/boot/intel-ucode.img` was previously configured to be loaded as part of initramfs, your bootloader configuration should include a reference to that file.

If you just remove the file, without modifying the bootloader configuration to remove/comment out the reference to the deleted file, then at boot, the bootloader will see that it is asked to load a file that does not exist. The bootloader is designed to be as generic as possible: it will not "know" that `intel-ucode.img` is not needed in this particular system, so it thinks "I must load that file, but I cannot because it is not there. This is an impossible task! Help!!!" and displays an error message.